# Splitting content by using delimiter

Tags: java

i am splitting the XML elements based delimiter `|`. The format of the XML elements are mentioned below.

```
start:23 | stop:43 | name:abc def
```

I am doing in a following way

```
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(oneLine, " | ");
// First line is "start"
if ( stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens() ) {
  String tmp = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
  if ( tmp.startsWith("start:")) {
    tmp = tmp.substring("start:".length());
      //  ----
```

But the problem is i am not able to get the last sub element `name:abc def`.
I am able to retrive only `abc` but not `def`.

Comment: A small edit would make your code an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), which would benefit everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.split()`:

```
String[] parts = split("\\s*\\|\\s*");
```

This will result in an array of length three.

Comment: make sure you trim the results too

Comment: `oneLine.split("\\s*\\|\\s*");`

Comment: +1 The JavaDocs for [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) explicitly suggest to use `String.split()`.

Comment: after using split, the the elements splitted into parts[0] is stat,parts[1] is stop and parts[2] is name.How do i assign each token to temp and check whether it starts with start: or stop:

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the spaces in your `(" | ")`.  Just this `("|")` will work.

Comment: The [reason](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29): _The characters in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens._